# use html in selectizeInput with R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I would like to use some html in the choices in select(ize)Input. Does anyone know a simple solution how to tell shiny to treat the options as HTML?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("test html use", label = "option", choices = c("<div title = 'This is option A'>opt A</div>", "opt B"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to treat the options of a `selectizeInput` as HTML, the `render` option is the way to go. The following code will render the ordinary output:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    br(),
    selectizeInput(
      "slctz", "Select something:",
      choices = list("option1" = "value1", "option2" = "value2"), 
      options = list( 
        render = I("{
        item: function(item, escape) { 
          return '<span>' + item.label + '</span>'; 
        },
        option: function(item, escape) { 
          return '<span>' + item.label + '</span>'; 
        }
      }")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

The `option` field is for the list of options, while the `item` field is for the selected options.

So if you want to style the options and the selected options, you can do so cleanly by adding a `class` attribute to the `span` elements, and by defining your CSS classes in the UI:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "
        .myoption {......}
        .myitem {......}
        "
      )
    )
  ),
  br(),
  selectizeInput(
    "slctz", "Select something:",
    choices = list("option1" = "value1", "option2" = "value2"), 
    options = list( 
      render = I("{
        item: function(item, escape) { 
          return '<span class=\"myitem\">' + item.label + '</span>'; 
        },
        option: function(item, escape) { 
          return '<span class=\"myoption\">' + item.label + '</span>'; 
        }
      }")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Could you please share some light in these doubts based on https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html?
(1)  It only mentions `option: function`, not `item: function`, could you explain what it does?
(2) It gives an example using `choices = cbind(name = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)` but it is not working for me. Could you provide an example passing a dataframe into choices?